# LinqPad Predicatebuider Expression call not working

Tags: linqpad, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I  am trying to get the examples working found at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

I have the following code:

```
 public partial class PriceList 
        {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc {get;set;}
        public DateTime? ValidFrom {get;set;}
        public DateTime? ValidTo{get;set;}

        public static Expression> IsCurrent()
        {
        return p => (p.ValidFrom == null || p.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now) && (p.ValidTo == null || p.ValidTo >= DateTime.Now);
        } 
        }


    void Main()
    {
        List plList = new List()
        {
        new PriceList(){ Name="Billy", Desc="Skilled", ValidFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10.0) , ValidTo= DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0) },
        new PriceList(){ Name="Jamie", Desc="Quick Study",ValidFrom =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10.0) , ValidTo= DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0) },
        new PriceList(){Name= "Larry", Desc= "Rookie",ValidFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10.0) , ValidTo= DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0) }
        };

     // Method 1
     var myResultList = plList.Where ( p => (p.ValidFrom == null || p.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now) 
     && (p.ValidTo == null || p.ValidTo >= DateTime.Now)).Dump();

    // Method 2

        plList.Where(PriceList.IsCurrent()).Dump(); // This does not work currently


    }
```

My question is between method 1 and method 2, this IsCurrent() method does not work the functionality of the code is identical, but when I call the Method 2 PriceList.IsCurrent() I get the following error.

Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   plList.AsQueryable().Where(PriceList.IsCurrent()).Dump();
```

PS, Your example doesn't compile, so I'm guessing that you mean

```
public static Expression<Func<PriceList, bool>> IsCurrent()
{
...
```

and

```
List<PriceList> plList = new List<PriceList>()
...
```